# MySQL Query Issue

Tags: mysql, count, where-in

I have the current database setup:

```
Forename | Surname | Department | Completion_Status
Tom        Smith     Sales        Started
Bob        Jones     Sales        Completed
Alison     Baines    Sales        Not Started
Arthur     Smith     Marketing    Started
Claire     Staines   Marketing    Completed
```

I am able to return the total number of rows without any problems and the total number where completion status is either Started or Completed but not in a single statement - however what I would like to do, in a single statement, is:

```
COUNT for Department As Total AND the COUNT for Department As Responses WHERE Completion_Status IN ('Started', 'Completed')
```

It would look something like this:

```
Department | Total | Responses
Sales        3       2
Marketing    2       2
```

Hope that makes sense!?

Thanks Homer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
department,
count(department) as total,
sum(if(completion_status  IN ('Started', 'Completed'),1,0)) as responses
from table
group by department
```

This is a more standard version

```
select 
department,
count(department) as total,
sum(case when completion_status in ('Started', 'Completed') then 1 else 0 end ) as responses
from table
group by department
```

Comment: Ok, that seems close - returns the correct totals but both responses are 1 and that's incorrect.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Re-checked - brings back the correct value for Total but def brings bck 1 for Responses - that's not right :(

Answer (score 1):

SELECT dept,

       *COUNT*(dept)              AS total,

       *COUNT*(completion_status) AS responses

FROM   tresults

WHERE  completion_status IN ( 'Started', 'Completed' )

GROUP  BY dept

ORDER  BY dep

Comment: You forgot to add department in the select list.

Comment: Taking your suggestion - SELECT dept, COUNT(dept) As Total AND COUNT(completion_status) As Responses FROM tresults WHERE completion_status IN ('Started', 'Completed') GROUP BY dept ORDER BY dept - this returns a SQL error - any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, re-checked - brings back value of 1 for everything - which is incorrect.

Comment: SELECT dept, 
       COUNT(dept)              AS total, 
       COUNT(completion_status) AS responses 
FROM   tresults 
WHERE  completion_status = 'Started' OR completion_status = 'Completed'
GROUP  BY dept 
ORDER  BY dep